# Pop up visibility

Tags: safe-core, web3auth

Is there any way to not have pop up while generating secret hash using lit and user can have seamless experience by doing nothing and just clicking on one button

Answer (score 0):

To ensure wallet security, we ask users to use at least an email address so they can safely interact with their Safe regardless of the app or project that configured it. One good reason for that also is to let them use the official Safe{Wallet} UI in case there is an issue.

So, as of today, no it is not possible.

Hope it helps,
Louis